# Bluez - transmit beacon and scan on same radio

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, bluez, beacon

I am using Bluez to set up a BLE beacon scanner on a standalone Linux box. I want it to do some form of self diagnosis on the radio (for some specific application reasons) and the way I'd like to do it is by transmitting a beacon (iBeacon or any other form) every so often and listening for this beacon on the same radio.

This is the setup that I have:

- Unit 1: standard off-the-shelf iBeacon.
- Unit 2: Ubuntu VM with CSR
  BLE radio. Running an iBeacon scanner and an iBeacon transmitter.
- Unit 3: Ubuntu VM with CSR BLE radio (different from the one in Unit
  2). Running an iBeacon scanner.

**Results:**

- Unit 3: is able to see Unit 1 and the iBeacon transmitted by Unit 2.
- Unit 2: is able to see Unit 1 but NOT the iBeacon transmitted by Unit 2.

Should it be possible for Unit 2 to see itself? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, a Bluetooth LE device cannot detect it's own transmission.**  This is nothing specific to BlueZ, Linux, or even the specific Bluetooth hardware you are using.  All BLE devices work this way including those on Android, iOS, Windows, Mac and other embedded platforms.

The limitation is baked into the hardware and the design of the Bluetooth specification.  **Why?  Because for non-experimental purposes, it just does not make sense to have a radio transmitter/receiver pick up its own transmission.**  Think of an old fashioned CB radio, which always turns off its receiver when transmitting.

You can, of course, add a second Bluetooth dongle on Linux, then use it to receive the transmission from the other interface.

Comment: BLE hardware typically have radios that can only do one thing at a time: either receive OR transmit. I don't think that is stated in the specification however. But it doesn't make sense to transmit and receive at the same time on the same frequency anyway.